# git add does not pick up new files added to an existing directory

Tags: git

I added some new files to an existing diretcory in my local repository (basically I did a cp of some files in another directory) However, when I do a git add . and run git status I see the following message:

nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Wondering what I need to do to add these files?

Thanks!

Comment: Which directory are you in when you run `git add .`, and what's the path to the new files? What does your `.gitignore` contain?

Comment: I am doing git add . from the top level dir. I have copied files to several differnt sub directories.I only have exceptions to include cerrtain files.

Comment: @user1801669 what about your `.git/info/exclude` file? Doesn't `git diff` you any output?

Comment: are your new files registering as untracked? Before adding the files check the git status to make sure they are in the correct repo. You could also try git add -u (to add untracked files)

Answer (score 2):

This should work regardless of the path

```
git add -A
```